# Rails 3 on Fedora issues

Tags: ruby, fedora

I have been trying to get Rails 3 installed in Fedora, it requires Ruby to be 1.8.7 or 1.9.2. Fedora official yum repos have Ruby 1.8.6 which is of no use. So I decided to compile it myself from the source, downloaded the source, compiled it and installed it successfully.

But this weird thing happens after the install, sudo gem or sudo ruby are not working, it just returns saying command not found.

```
which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]

sudo ruby
sudo: ruby: command not found

sudo echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Am I missing something, why doesnt it find ruby when its in the PATH?

Comment: Are you sure the `ruby` executable is in `root`'s `$PATH`? The line you posted doesn't show that, since obviously the variable expansion happens in your shell, not `root`'s.

Comment: Shouldn't sudo use the same PATH that is used by the current user, I finally was able to get around it by setting an alias to sudo, "alias sudo=sudo env PATH=$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

1. check your PATH variable (set in your .bash_profile or .bashrc file, add /usr/local/bin to the front of the PATH:

   PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
2. I'd recommend that you check out RVM -- so far the best way to install and switch between different Ruby versions and to maintain Gems independently for each version!

   https://rvm.io

   Using RVM is much easier than compiling by hand, and it keeps all your Gems organized by Ruby version!

   There's also a RailsCast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm